# Books or articles that prove the following result or similar.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I was wondering if the following result had already been proven somewhere, for a sequence  $\left(X_n\right)$ of non-negative integrable random variables (conditions on integrability may be stronger) on $\left(\mathbb{P}, \Omega,\mathcal{F}\right)$ with $p \ge 1$ (a user has already pointed how the case $p> 1$ is trivial.) :

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} \dfrac{ \left(\sup _{m \geq 1} \dfrac{1}{m} \sum_{k=1}^{m} \mathbb{P}\left(\left|X_{k}\right|>n\right) \right)^p}{n^p} < \infty, \, \text{almost everywhere.}$$

the closest result I found was Lemma 3 from maximal inequalities of weak type by S. Sawyer, but the lemma assumes the random variables to be identically distributed.

The lemma is enunciated as follows :

$\textbf{LEMMA 3}$.

Let $\left\{f_{n}(x)\right\}$ be a sequence of non-negative integrable functions on $X$, having the same distribution function $F(\lambda)=m\left[\left\{x: f_{n}(x) \geqq \lambda\right\}\right]$. Then, for any $p>1$
$$
\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{f_{n}(x)^{p}}{n^{p}}<\infty
$$
almost everywhere.

any references will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 'Almost surely' does not make sense since the left side is not random.

Comment: @geetha290krm,  meant to say almost everywhere

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} \dfrac{ \left(\sup _{m \geq 1} \dfrac{1}{m} \sum_{k=1}^{m} \mathbb{P}\left(\left|X_{k}\right|>n\right) \right)^p}{n^p} \leq  \sum_{n \ge 1} \dfrac1 {n^{p}}$$  since probability of any event is $\leq 1$.

Comment: that's true, thanks much for pointing that out, I guess I'll look for the case p = 1, do you think I should make a separate post or just edit my original post (I'm asking because then your answer wouldn't match)